# Laravel Form Input hidden keep returning empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, input

## Description

I have a form

```
<form method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://site/account/1003/destroy">
  <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
  <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="pBRx8u17C6KHFxzfhatx0BpnmOF5x55EWSP2lpis">
  <input name="id" type="hidden" value="1003">
  <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger mr10">No</a>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg"> Yes </button>
</form>
```

As you can see the id has the value of `1003`.

---

## Attempt

I'ved to test in my destroy() function

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    dd(Input::all());
    ...
```

I got

```
array:3 [▼
  "_method" => "DELETE"
  "_token" => "pBRx8u17C6KHFxzfhatx0BpnmOF5x55EWSP2lpis"
  "id" => "" <------ empty 
]
```

I double check everything. I could not seem to know what is the cause of my `id` to be empty while I can clearly see it in the HTML in my browser.

How can I debug this further?

Comment: Is the id correctly sent to the server? Use the network tab in the developer console to inspect the data sent with the post request.

Comment: Have you tried renaming the input to something else?

Comment: Try changing the name of the field for example to `name="my_id"`

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you could also use variable `$id`

Comment: @SzőkePéter -- Nice Tip, I will go a head and do that now.

Answer (score 0):

The Input facade is deprecated (as of 5.0?). Try using the Request class

```
public function destroy(Request $request) {
    $id = $request->input('id');
}
```

Comment: Quick note: Input facade is not in `config/app.php` by default, but you could still add `'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,` to 'aliases' to make it work

Comment: There is also `$id` as function argument in his example